# spring roo update maven configuration error

Tags: maven, spring-roo

I'm running springsource tool suite 2.9.1.  After i checked in a spring roo project, the project is not recognizing it's a dynamic web project and when i try to update maven configuration, it gives this error

```
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Configuration".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.springsource.sts.roo.ui.internal.maven.RooProjectConfigurator.doConfigure(RooProjectConfigurator.java:56)
    at com.springsource.sts.maven.AbstractSpringProjectConfigurator.configure(AbstractSpringProjectConfigurator.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.AbstractLifecycleMapping.configure(AbstractLifecycleMapping.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.UpdateConfigurationJob.runInWorkspace(UpdateConfigurationJob.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

any ideas anyone?

Comment: What is the Maven version you are using?